# How can i replace HTML's element content by another HTML's element content with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Im working on wordpress and for some reason i can't edit or even find plugin's html template. My question is : Can i just simply replace HTML element content with another HTML element content via CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: if you copy past in the same page yes and use some event css named pseudo class like :hover, :checked, :active ... is poor and ridiculous but no judgment i was a beginner and you need to learn in your step as you can.  The deal here display:none; display block

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript:

```
 <p id="p1"> old content !</p>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text here !";
    </script>
```

Comment: Can i swap content between two html elements? @BqNqNNN

Comment: yes you can :

use JavaScript again:

<script>
 var swapVariable = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = swapVariable;

 </script>

Answer (score 0):

CSS is short for Cascading StyleSheet therefore it is not able to change text to other text.

You have 2 possibilities now:

1. Find a way in your CMS to change the HTML content.
2. Learn JS and use it accordingly. (the uglier solution)